# Showing wrong Developer/Company name on Itunes apps?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store, apple-id

I have registered my developer account with `ABC Private limited` company ,

https://appleid.apple.com/ in this link also , There is no information about `XYZ R&D Private Limited`

But when we are uploading build on iTunes ,it is showing `XYZ R&D Private Limited` below the app name and at bottom side , `ABC Private limited` is showing as `Seller` name .

How can i remove `XYZ R&D Private Limited`  from my apps .

**Itunes**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought this can be changed in iTunes Connect when adding a new version of the app, but I'm probably wrong as I don't see this option for my own apps. 
Everything I can find on StackOverflow or Apple Forums, it seems you have to contact iTunes Connect support to change this name.
Hope this link works: https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/SC1101/subtopic/30004/solution/select — Here you have the option to contact them by phone or email! I used this once, and they're very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JeroenJK finally got an option for call support ,

Comment: Good. Curious how this will be solved — if they're able to change this!